# Removing duplicates from two arrays in javascript based on a single attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two arrays in javascript, where i want to do two different operations

1. Map an attribute upon each element in each lists
2. filter out none unique values based on an attribute

I have this function so far

```
export function generateDisplayedLabels(systemLabels, masterState){
  const mappedSystemlabels = systemLabels.map(label => Object.assign(label, {type: "system"}))
  const mappedMasterlabels = masterState.map(label => Object.assign(label, {type: "master"}))
  const displayedLabels = _.union(mappedSystemlabels, mappedMasterState);
  return displayedLabels

}
```

This would work except for the fact, that whenever i map over the objects in the beginning, the "unique" elements are no longer unique, because they have another attribute mapped upon it. Is there a time efficient way, that i can filter out the none unique elements, ignoring the attribute, that have been mapped onto it.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: You could use [`_.unionBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#unionBy) which takes a function as a second parameter which lets you choose a field or value by which the uniqueness is computed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let ar1 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'stack',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'react',
  },
];

let ar2 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'javascript',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'overflow',
  },
 {
    id: 2,
    name: 'react',
  },
];

console.log(_.unionBy(ar1, ar2, 'id'));
console.log("======");
console.log(_.unionBy(ar1, ar2, 'name'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```